# How do I move a component in a layout?

Tags: java, swing, components, jlabel

How do I move a component in a frame while I am using a layout? I have tried this:

```
    System.out.println(test1.getLocation());
    int oy = test1.getY();
    int ox = test1.getX();
    oy++;
    ox++;
    test1.setLocation(ox, oy);
    validate();
    test1.validate();
    System.out.println(test1.getLocation());
```

The first location is the same as the last location. I know that you can't change the location while in the layout normally, but how do you accomplish it? I have asked a similar question before and never got an answer. I have searched all over the internet for this, but I haven't found an answer.

TL;DR - How do you move a component?

Comment: Swing gives each component `BorderLayout` as a default layout manager. Try turning it off for the panel with `setLayoutManager(null)` to enable absolute positioning.

Comment: @millimoose: No, the default layout of `JFrame` is `BorderLayout`; the default layout of `JPanel` is `FlowLayout`; absolute positioning is _not_ required.

Comment: See also this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2562685/230513) and [variation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2563350/230513).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the `LayoutManager` of the panel is setting the location of the label for you.

What you need to do is set the layout to `null` by:

```
setLayout(null);
```

This will make it so the frame/panel doesn't try to layout the components by itself.

Then call `setBounds(Rectangle rect)` on the label. Like so:

`lbl.setBounds(new Rectangle(new Point(200, 300), lbl.getPreferedSize()));`
This should place the component where you want it.

However, if you don't have a really great reason to lay out the components by yourself, it is usually a better idea to use `LayoutManager`s to work in your favour.

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) is a great tutorial on getting started with using `LayoutManager`s, if though you must use absolute then have a look at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html) tutorial

Comment: technically correct, but not recommened - simply don't go without a LayoutManager, ever.

Answer (score 3):

may to help you to look at [DragLayout](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2011/10/23/drag-layout/) and to combine with [ComponentMover](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/14/moving-windows/), made by `@camickr`

Answer (score 2):

The `setLocation()` method works when setting the layout to `null`. If you are using a layout manager then one choice would be that you remove the component from its container and add it back using the new layout constraints.