# Creating GUI with Windows Builder Pro

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

Is the Windows Builder Pro GUI designer not for designing GUI for games like chess or connect four, but rather for basic GUI?

I'm asking this because all the tutorials that I watch online are building very basic windows and no one is really building a GUI for a game like checkers.

EDIT: How would I go about implementing a checkers board with the Windows Builder Pro?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *"all the tutorials that I watch online are building very basic windows"*  Makes sense.  What do you expect them to build, a space shuttle?

Comment: No, but something a bit more complex than a basic window for which I wouldn't need the GUI Designer...

Comment: The tutorials were not meant to be rigorous or all encompassing. You need to use your knowledge of Swing to extend these GUI's and *any* GUI.

Comment: This is still not a real answerable question other than: try to write code to implement it. I'm afraid that I have to vote to close this question.

Comment: See also this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2562685/230513) and [variation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2563350/230513).

Answer (score 2):

The GUI builder is for any GUI you'd like to make including chess and connect four. The more extras you want to add, the more you'll need to do some custom coding, but that's the same as with any GUI code generator. The tutorials are to introduce folks to the use of the tool, not as a means for covering all uses of the tool. I will add that if you are not very familiar with the Swing library that you should avoid use of code generation tools as you will find it very frustrating when you need to push the envelope as we always must do with these tools.

Just where are you stuck?

Comment: The more I think on this, the less I think that your question is appropriate for SO. You don't tell us of any problem you are having that we can help you fix.

Comment: So having a chess piece move wouldn't be a part of the GUI builder because it's a bit more complex right?

Comment: well its kind of hard to ask an appropriate question because asking how to implement a chess GUI in WindowsBuilder Pro would be too broad.

Comment: The code generator can build the GUI framework, but custom drawings would be your responsibility. A chess piece could be held as an ImageIcon in a JLabel, but still you're going to need to do a lot of coding yourself. I suggest your going through the Swing tutorials to learn the underpinnings of the library.