# how to improve image dragging performance

Tags: java, swing, draggable

I'm trying to set up dragging of an image over a grid of Jlabels.
it's working fine, but the image is "refreshing" and sometimes lags behind the mouse.

Is there  a way to improve this and get a perfectly "smooth" movement of the image ?

EDIT: ok now, thanks to Andrew Thompson's advice I updated the paint() method to paintComponent(). But now why does my component disappear when I drag it? I'm probably missing something here...

EDIT2: why is the following behaviour: when using paint() method the component displays on top of the JLabels. But when using paintComponent() the component disappears being masked by the opaque Jlabels?

```
import java.awt.*;  
import java.awt.event.*;  
import java.io.*;  
import java.net.*;  

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;  
import javax.swing.*;  
import javax.swing.event.*;  

public class DragNDrop {

    public static void main(String[] args)  
    {  
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");  
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  
        f.setContentPane(new DragPanel());    
        f.pack();
        f.setLocation(200,200);  
        f.setVisible(true);  
    }  

}

class DragPanel extends JPanel {

    JLabel[][] labels;

    SelectableAction action;  
    Image image;  
    Point p;  

    public DragPanel()  
    {  

        p = new Point();  

        setOpaque(true);   
        createLabels();


        action = new SelectableAction(this);  
        addMouseListener(action);  
        addMouseMotionListener(action);  
    }  

    private void createLabels() {


            labels = new JLabel[8][8];

            Dimension dim50 = new Dimension(50,50);
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            for (int x=0;x<8;x++){

                for (int y=0;y<8;y++){

                    labels[x][y] = new JLabel();
                    labels[x][y].setOpaque(true);
                    labels[x][y].setPreferredSize(dim50);
                    String str = new String("("+x+","+y+")");
                    labels[x][y].setText(str);

                    if ((x+y) % 2 == 0){
                        labels[x][y].setBackground(Color.lightGray);
                    } else
                    {
                        labels[x][y].setBackground(Color.white);
                    }

                    gbc.gridx = x;
                    gbc.gridy = 7-y;
                    this.add(labels[x][y],gbc);


                }
                URL url = getClass().getResource("images/50px-Knight.pgn");  
                Image img;
                try {
                    img = ImageIO.read(url);
                    labels[0][0].setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
                } catch (IOException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }  



            }
    }

    public JLabel[][] getLabels()  
    {  
        return labels;  
    }  


    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)  
    {  
        super.paintComponent(g);  

        if(action.dragging)  
            g.drawImage(image, p.x, p.y, this); 

    }  

    public void setImage(Image i)  
    {  
        image = i;  
    }  

    public void setOrigin(Point p)  
    {  
        this.p = p;  
        repaint();  
    }  


}

/** 
 * Mouse code to enable image dragging 
 */  
class SelectableAction extends MouseInputAdapter  
{  
    DragPanel MyPanel;  
    Image selectedImage;  
    boolean dragging;  
    Rectangle r;  
    Point offset;  

    public SelectableAction(DragPanel dp)  
    {  
        MyPanel = dp;   
        dragging = false;  
        offset = new Point();  
    }  
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)  
    {  
        Point p = e.getPoint();  
        JLabel[][] labels = MyPanel.getLabels();  
        for(int i = 0; i < labels.length; i++)  
        {  
            for (int j=0;j<labels[0].length;j++){

                r = labels[i][j].getBounds();  
                if(r.contains(p))  
                {  
                    if ( ((ImageIcon)labels[i][j].getIcon()).getImage() != null) {
                    selectedImage = ((ImageIcon)labels[i][j].getIcon()).getImage();  
                    MyPanel.setImage(selectedImage);  
                    labels[i][j].setIcon(null);
                    offset.x = p.x - r.x;  
                    offset.y = p.y - r.y;  
                    dragging = true;  
                    MyPanel.setOrigin(new Point(r.x, r.y));
                    break;  
                    }
                }  

            }

        }  
    }  

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)  
    {  
        Point p = e.getPoint();  
        JLabel[][] labels = MyPanel.getLabels();  
        for(int i = 0; i < labels.length; i++)  
        {  
            for (int j=0;j<labels[0].length; j++){

                r = labels[i][j].getBounds();  
                if(r.contains(p))  {

                    ImageIcon tmpIcon = new ImageIcon(selectedImage);
                    labels[i][j].setIcon(tmpIcon);
                    MyPanel.repaint();  
                    dragging = false;

                }
            }
        }

    }  

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)  
    {  
        if(dragging)  
        {  
            r.x = e.getX() - offset.x;  
            r.y = e.getY() - offset.y;  
            MyPanel.setOrigin(new Point(r.x, r.y));  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Change `public void paint(Graphics g)` to `public void paintComponent(Graphics g)` (and change the call to `super` as well).

Comment: thanks. Ive tried it already, but it causes the component to disappear during the dragging...

Comment: It disappears because you have opaque children components that paint themselves above. Otherwise, it runs correctly and smoothly on my computer. I tried with this image: "`http://i1195.photobucket.com/albums/aa398/EricMMann/Design1/Knight.png`" and it was ok.

Comment: Why does that code not import anything from [`java.awt.dnd`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/dnd/package-frame.html)?

Comment: sorry, but when I try with this code: 
    public void paintcomponent(Graphics g)  
    {  
        super.paintComponent(g);  
        
        if(action.dragging)  
            g.drawImage(image, p.x, p.y, this); 
             
    }, the component dissapears and I don"t understand why. I should be missing something...

Comment: @Andrew Thompson: I found this code on the net to drag n drop components but I didn't look at java.awt.dnd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

+1 to AndrewThompson and GuillaumePolet comments. especially:

> It disappears because you have opaque children components that paint
>   themselves above.

to overcome this we dont need/want to override `paintComponent(..)` instead we want to override `paintChildren(..)` and call `super.paintChildren(..)` followed by our custom code. Thus all components will be drawn in call to `super` and our image will be drawn after, thus making it appear/visible above all others.

Replace the overridden `paintComponent` with below code and it will work:

```
@Override
protected void paintChildren(Graphics g) {
    super.paintChildren(g);

    if (action.dragging) {
        g.drawImage(image, p.x, p.y, null);//also notice i use null and not this, unless the class you are using extends ImageObserver no need for this
    }
}
```

Comment: See also this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2562685/230513) and [variation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2563350/230513).

Comment: thanks!!! +1 it is working this way :-) But ... the component is still lagging ... maybe I could use an overridden paintComponent with a JLayeredPane ?

Comment: Its not lagging at all for me? No offence maybe PC a bit sluggish? But If you need to why not rather just draw the outline of the piece when dragging instead of the image itself?

Comment: My PC can't be sluggish!! it's a Linux !! (I'm joking ;-)) But I see a real difference of performance for instance if I set the JLabels to setOpaque(false) the image's movement is perfectly smooth. But if I put back the setOpaque(true) on the JLabels it's lagging. even with @Override paintChildren()