# Custom JComponent not showing up on JLayeredPane

Tags: java, swing, jcomponent, jlayeredpane

I'm trying to create a chess interface in Java and I'm using a `JLayeredPane` to put the pieces on top of my chessboard image. The problem is that the pieces are not added to the layered pane.

This is the code for my `DragImage` class (every piece is going to be an instance of this class which you can drag and drop on the chessboard).

```
class DragImage extends JComponent implements MouseMotionListener {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        int imageWidth = 52, imageHeight = 52;
        int imageX, imageY;
        Image img;

        public DragImage(Image i) {
            img = i;
            repaint();
            addMouseMotionListener(this);
        }

        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            imageX = e.getX();
            imageY = e.getY();
            repaint();
        }

        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

            g2.drawImage(img, imageX, imageY, this);
        }

    }
```

And this is the code for the `JPanel`.

The image addresses are correct but they aren't showing up on the panel.

```
class MyPanel extends JPanel {
        private JLayeredPane layeredPane;
        private JLabel imageContainer = new JLabel();
        private ImageIcon img;

        MyPanel() {
            super();
            img = new ImageIcon("chessboard.png");
            this.imageContainer.setIcon(img);
            this.layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
            layeredPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(416, 416));
            layeredPane.add(imageContainer, 50);
            imageContainer.setBounds(0, 0, img.getIconWidth(),
                    img.getIconHeight());
            int pozx = 52, pozy = 52;
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                    if(tabla[i][j]!="--"){
                    DragImage img = new DragImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("pieces\\" + tabla[i][j] + ".png"));
                    //System.out.println("pieces\\" + tabla[i][j] + ".png");
                    img.setBounds(pozx,pozy,img.imageWidth,img.imageHeight);
                    layeredPane.add(img,100);   //this doesn't work
                    }
                    pozx+=52;
                }
                pozy+=52;
                pozx=52;
            }

            this.add(layeredPane);
        }
}
```

...

```
frame = new JFrame();
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.setSize(800, 600);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
panel = new MyPanel();
frame.add(panel);
frame.pack();
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Create frame, set size, add panel, pack, setvisible.

Comment: *"The image addresses are correct but they aren't showing up on the panel."*  Really?  Try this experiment.  `String path = "pieces\\" + tabla[i][j] + ".png"; File f = new File(path); System.out.println("File exists: " + file.exists());`.  I'll **bet** that prints `File exists: false` (after you fix any small typos. that might prevent it from compiling)..

Comment: See also this working [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2562685/230513) and [variation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2563350/230513).

Comment: @AndrewThompson That printed true for all the files so that's not the problem...

Comment: @trashgod thank you that helped a lot. i used code from that example and it works. problem solved.

Comment: You can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17463/163188).

Answer (score 0):

first use the Layeredpane then attach two panels one for image and another panel for components and the second panel must be palete layer then the components will appear..