# Moving pieces in Chess java

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener, chess

```
for(y=0;y<length;y++){
    for(x=0;x<width;x++){

            grid[x][y]=new JButton(" ");
            grid[x][y].addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                ((JButton)e.getSource()).setBorder(border);;
                System.out.println("Where do you want to move this piece");
            }
        }); 
            grid[x][y].addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent r){
                    grid[x][y]=grid[x][y-1];
                    ((JButton)r.getSource()).setBorder(border);;
                    System.out.println("Derp");
                }
            });
            frame.add(grid[x][y]);
    }
}
```

I want to click a piece and then when you click a different square, the piece will move up one. I know this is wrong and I will show the legal moves but for right now I need to get the pieces moving. Please help!!
I am completely stuck until I can get this figured out.

Comment: So `grid` is an array of `JButton` and you are just moving buttons around in the grid? - That's what the code looks like. You should consider splitting your "game state" and your "game view" into different classes.

Comment: What makes you think the code is wrong?

Comment: See also this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2562685/230513) and [variation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2563350/230513).

Comment: I just want the first Jbutton that I clicked moved to the position of the second spot I clicked. e=r if it were that simple

Comment: Maybe put in a call to `repaint()`. Graphics can be finicky so it's good to borrow from a working example.

Answer (score 2):

First off, make sure all syntax is correct as I see double semi colons on this line:

```
((JButton)e.getSource()).setBorder(border);;
```

Also this line should be ouside the ActioneListener, as you want to set the border of the button, not when you click but when you setup the actions.

*If you don't want to change much in the current way you are doing this, try this:* You should create a **GameObject** class have it extend *JButton* also have it set the border of the button to a size that you will like. Now create a *grid[x][y]* of game objects. Then create a **Piece** class and a **Space** class, both should extends *GameObject*. The piece class should overwrite the *paint(Graphics g)* method of the *JButton* and render an image of the piece. Then when you click on a piece raise a flag and keep a reference of this piece in the main class, then when you click on a space the program will swap between the two game objects. (Note: You'll have to populate the grid with Space class instances.)

Dealing with JButtons directly as "Pieces" can be tricky and is not a very good way to implementing a Chess game.

**I strongly recommend if you really want to create a chess game, to take a look at this tutorial:**

http://proghammer.wordpress.com/2010/08/08/chess00-introduction/

It's for beginners, step by step. I created a chess game with this :D Enjoy.

Comment: I just want the first Jbutton that I clicked moved to the position of the second spot I clicked. e=r if it were that simple