# How to proberly reset JPane gridl of JButtons with icons?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, keylistener, mouselistener

So I have a bejeweled like game that is created by taking a JPanel giving it a grid layout then putting  buttons in the grid and assigning icons to the buttons. I'm trying to make the game restart when a certain key is pressed but I'm having several issues. Issue one is that when the game board is reset it does not call the main method and also the buttons rearrange but when the mouse hovers over a icon the icon reverts to the icon that was originally there. Another problem Im having is that the keylistener only takes input if no buttons have been pressed. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!! Thanks

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

public class Jewelswithec implements MouseListener, KeyListener{

  private static int rows;
  private static int columns;
  private static int numJewels;
  private static JFrame frame = new JFrame("Yakobian's Jewels");
  private JButton[][] buttonArray = null;
  private int buttonRow;
  private int buttonColumn;
  private int count = 1;
  private int[] bx = new int[2];
  private int[] by = new int[2];
  private boolean adjacent;
  private int[][] horizantal;
  private boolean[][] marked;
  private int turnCount;

  public Jewelswithec() {
    new Jewelswithec(8, 10, 4);
  }

  public Jewelswithec (int rows, int columns, int numJewels) {
    try {
      UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
    }

    this.rows = rows;
    this.columns = columns;
    this.numJewels = numJewels;

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(500,500);
    marked = new boolean[rows][columns];
    JPanel board = new JPanel(new GridLayout(rows, columns));
    frame.getContentPane().add(board, "Center");
    buttonArray = new JButton[rows][columns]; 
    board.setFocusable(true);
    board.requestFocusInWindow();
    board.addKeyListener(this);

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {       
        buttonArray[i][j] = new JButton();
        board.add(buttonArray[i][j]);
        buttonArray[i][j].addMouseListener(this);
        int randomNum = (int)(Math.random()*(numJewels)); 

        if(randomNum == 0) {
          buttonArray[i][j].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
          ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("circle.png");
          int scale = 7;
          int width = ii.getIconWidth();
          int newWidth = width / scale;
          buttonArray[i][j].setIcon(new ImageIcon(ii.getImage().getScaledInstance(newWidth, -1,
                                                                                  java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH))); 
          buttonArray[i][j].setBorderPainted(false);  
          buttonArray[i][j].setFocusPainted(false);  
          buttonArray[i][j].setContentAreaFilled(false);

        }
        else if(randomNum == 1) {
          buttonArray[i][j].setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
          ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("triangle.png");
          int scale = 13;
          int width = ii.getIconWidth();
          int newWidth = width / scale;
          buttonArray[i][j].setIcon(new ImageIcon(ii.getImage().getScaledInstance(newWidth, -1,
                                                                                  java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH))); 
          buttonArray[i][j].setBorderPainted(false);  
          buttonArray[i][j].setFocusPainted(false);  
          buttonArray[i][j].setContentAreaFilled(false);
        }
        else if(randomNum == 2) {
          buttonArray[i][j].setBackground(Color.BLUE);
          ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("square.png");
          int scale = 14;
          int width = ii.getIconWidth();
          int newWidth = width / scale;
          buttonArray[i][j].setIcon(new ImageIcon(ii.getImage().getScaledInstance(newWidth, -1,
                                                                                  java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH))); 
          buttonArray[i][j].setBorderPainted(false);  
          buttonArray[i][j].setFocusPainted(false);  
          buttonArray[i][j].setContentAreaFilled(false);
        }
        else if(randomNum == 3) {
          buttonArray[i][j].setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
          ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("star.png");
          int scale = 12;
          int width = ii.getIconWidth();
          int newWidth = width / scale;
          buttonArray[i][j].setIcon(new ImageIcon(ii.getImage().getScaledInstance(newWidth, -1,
                                                                                  java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH))); 
          buttonArray[i][j].setBorderPainted(false);  
          buttonArray[i][j].setFocusPainted(false);  
          buttonArray[i][j].setContentAreaFilled(false);
        }
        else if(randomNum == 4) {
          buttonArray[i][j].setBackground(Color.CYAN);
          ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("pentagon.png");
          int scale = 14;
          int width = ii.getIconWidth();
          int newWidth = width / scale;
          buttonArray[i][j].setIcon(new ImageIcon(ii.getImage().getScaledInstance(newWidth, -1,
                                                                                  java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH))); 
          buttonArray[i][j].setBorderPainted(false);  
          buttonArray[i][j].setFocusPainted(false);  
          buttonArray[i][j].setContentAreaFilled(false);
        }
        else if(randomNum == 5) {
          buttonArray[i][j].setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
          ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("diamond.png");
          int scale = 13;
          int width = ii.getIconWidth();
          int newWidth = width / scale;
          buttonArray[i][j].setIcon(new ImageIcon(ii.getImage().getScaledInstance(newWidth, -1,
                                                                                  java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH))); 
          buttonArray[i][j].setBorderPainted(false);  
          buttonArray[i][j].setFocusPainted(false);  
          buttonArray[i][j].setContentAreaFilled(false);
        }
        else if(randomNum == 6) {
          buttonArray[i][j].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
          ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("hexagon.png");
          int scale = 12;
          int width = ii.getIconWidth();
          int newWidth = width / scale;
          buttonArray[i][j].setIcon(new ImageIcon(ii.getImage().getScaledInstance(newWidth, -1,
                                                                                  java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH))); 
          buttonArray[i][j].setBorderPainted(false);  
          buttonArray[i][j].setFocusPainted(false);  
          buttonArray[i][j].setContentAreaFilled(false);
        }
        else {
          buttonArray[i][j].setBackground(Color.RED);
          ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("octagon.png");
          int scale = 14;
          int width = ii.getIconWidth();
          int newWidth = width / scale;
          buttonArray[i][j].setIcon(new ImageIcon(ii.getImage().getScaledInstance(newWidth, -1,
                                                                                  java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH))); 
          buttonArray[i][j].setBorderPainted(false);  
          buttonArray[i][j].setFocusPainted(false);  
          buttonArray[i][j].setContentAreaFilled(false);
        }

        buttonArray[i][j].setVisible(true); 
      }
    }

    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

  public int findRow(JButton b) {

    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
      for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
        if(b == buttonArray[i][j]) {
          buttonRow = i;
        }
      }
    }
    return buttonRow;
  }

  public int findColumn(JButton b) {

    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
      for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
        if(b == buttonArray[i][j]) {
          buttonColumn = j;
        }
      }
    }
    return buttonColumn;
  }

  public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) { }

  public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) { }

  public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    if(e.getKeyChar() == 'R') {
      System.out.println("dfjaljfda");
      new Jewelswithec();
    }
  }          

  public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event) { }

  public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) { }

  public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

    JButton b = (JButton) e.getSource();
    int pressY = this.findColumn(b);
    int pressX = this.findRow(b);
    this.highlightShape(pressX, pressY);
  }

  public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) { 

    JButton b = (JButton) e.getSource();
    int pressY = this.findColumn(b);
    int pressX = this.findRow(b);
    this.originalColor(pressX, pressY);
  }

  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

    JButton b = (JButton) e.getSource();
    by[count - 1] = this.findColumn(b);
    bx[count - 1] = this.findRow(b);
    count++;

    if(count > 2) {
      count = 1;

      if((bx[1] == bx[0] && by[0] == by[1]) || ((Math.abs(bx[0] - bx[1]) > 1) || (Math.abs(by[0] - by[1]) > 1))) {
        adjacent = false;
      }
      else {
        adjacent = true;
        swapColors(bx[0], bx[1], by[0], by[1]);
      }
    }
    this.checkForWin();
  }

  public void highlightShape(int bx, int by) {

    if(buttonArray[bx][by].getBackground() == Color.BLACK) {

      ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("highlightcircle.png");
      int scale = 7;
      int width = ii.getIconWidth();
      int newWidth = width / scale;
      buttonArray[bx][by].setIcon(new ImageIcon(ii.getImage().getScaledInstance(newWidth, -1,
                                                                                java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH))); 
      buttonArray[bx][by].setBorderPainted(false);  
      buttonArray[bx][by].setFocusPainted(false);  
      buttonArray[bx][by].setContentAreaFilled(false);
    }

    if(buttonArray[bx][by].getBackground() == Color.ORANGE) {

      ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("highlighttriangle.png");
      int scale = 13;
      int width = ii.getIconWidth();
      int newWidth = width / scale;
      buttonArray[bx][by].setIcon(new ImageIcon(ii.getImage().getScaledInstance(newWidth, -1,
                                                                                java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH))); 
      buttonArray[bx][by].setBorderPainted(false);  
      buttonArray[bx][by].setFocusPainted(false);  
      buttonArray[bx][by].setContentAreaFilled(false);
    }

    if(buttonArray[bx][by].getBackground() == Color.BLUE) {

      ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("highlightsquare.png");
      int scale = 14;
      int width = ii.getIconWidth();
      int newWidth = width / scale;
      buttonArray[bx][by].setIcon(new ImageIcon(ii.getImage().getScaledInstance(newWidth, -1,
                                                                                java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH))); 
      buttonArray[bx][by].setBorderPainted(false);  
      buttonArray[bx][by].setFocusPainted(false);  
      buttonArray[bx][by].setContentAreaFilled(false);
    }

    if(buttonArray[bx][by].getBackground() == Color.DARK_GRAY) {

      ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("highlightstar.png");
      int scale = 12;
      int width = ii.getIconWidth();
      int newWidth = width / scale;
      buttonArray[bx][by].setIcon(new ImageIcon(ii.getImage().getScaledInstance(newWidth, -1,
                                                                                java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH))); 
      buttonArray[bx][by].setBorderPainted(false);  
      buttonArray[bx][by].setFocusPainted(false);  
      buttonArray[bx][by].setContentAreaFilled(false);
    }

    if(buttonArray[bx][by].getBackground() == Color.CYAN) {

      ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("highlightpentagon.png");
      int scale = 14;
      int width = ii.getIconWidth();
      int newWidth = width / scale;
      buttonArray[bx][by].setIcon(new ImageIcon(ii.getImage().getScaledInstance(newWidth, -1,
                                                                                java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH))); 
      buttonArray[bx][by].setBorderPainted(false);  
      buttonArray[bx][by].setFocusPainted(false);  
      buttonArray[bx][by].setContentAreaFilled(false);
    }

    if(buttonArray[bx][by].getBackground() == Color.YELLOW) {

      ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("highlightdiamond.png");
      int scale = 13;
      int width = ii.getIconWidth();
      int newWidth = width / scale;
      buttonArray[bx][by].setIcon(new ImageIcon(ii.getImage().getScaledInstance(newWidth, -1,
                                                                                java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH))); 
      buttonArray[bx][by].setBorderPainted(false);  
      buttonArray[bx][by].setFocusPainted(false);  
      buttonArray[bx][by].setContentAreaFilled(false);
    }

    if(buttonArray[bx][by].getBackground() == Color.GREEN) {

      ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("highlighthexagon.png");
      int scale = 12;
      int width = ii.getIconWidth();
      int newWidth = width / scale;
      buttonArray[bx][by].setIcon(new ImageIcon(ii.getImage().getScaledInstance(newWidth, -1,
                                                                                java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH))); 
      buttonArray[bx][by].setBorderPainted(false);  
      buttonArray[bx][by].setFocusPainted(false);  
      buttonArray[bx][by].setContentAreaFilled(false);
    }

    if(buttonArray[bx][by].getBackground() == Color.RED) {

      ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("highlightoctagon.png");
      int scale = 14;
      int width = ii.getIconWidth();
      int newWidth = width / scale;
      buttonArray[bx][by].setIcon(new ImageIcon(ii.getImage().getScaledInstance(newWidth, -1,
                                                                                java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH))); 
      buttonArray[bx][by].setBorderPainted(false);  
      buttonArray[bx][by].setFocusPainted(false);  
      buttonArray[bx][by].setContentAreaFilled(false);
    }

    if(buttonArray[bx][by].getBackground() == Color.GRAY) {

      ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("highlightmark.png");
      int scale = 14;
      int width = ii.getIconWidth();
      int newWidth = width / scale;
      buttonArray[bx][by].setIcon(new ImageIcon(ii.getImage().getScaledInstance(newWidth, -1,
                                                                                java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH))); 
      buttonArray[bx][by].setBorderPainted(false);  
      buttonArray[bx][by].setFocusPainted(false);  
      buttonArray[bx][by].setContentAreaFilled(false);
    }
  }

  public void originalColor(int bx, int by) {

    if(buttonArray[bx][by].getBackground() == Color.BLACK) {

      ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("circle.png");
      int scale = 7;
      int width = ii.getIconWidth();
      int newWidth = width / scale;
      buttonArray[bx][by].setIcon(new ImageIcon(ii.getImage().getScaledInstance(newWidth, -1,
                                                                                java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH))); 
      buttonArray[bx][by].setBorderPainted(false);  
      buttonArray[bx][by].setFocusPainted(false);  
      buttonArray[bx][by].setContentAreaFilled(false);
    }

    if(buttonArray[bx][by].getBackground() == Color.ORANGE) {

      ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("triangle.png");
      int scale = 13;
      int width = ii.getIconWidth();
      int newWidth = width / scale;
      buttonArray[bx][by].setIcon(new ImageIcon(ii.getImage().getScaledInstance(newWidth, -1,
                                                                                java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH))); 
      buttonArray[bx][by].setBorderPainted(false);  
      buttonArray[bx][by].setFocusPainted(false);  
      buttonArray[bx][by].setContentAreaFilled(false);
    }

    if(buttonArray[bx][by].getBackground() == Color.BLUE) {

      ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("square.png");
      int scale = 14;
      int width = ii.getIconWidth();
      int newWidth = width / scale;
      buttonArray[bx][by].setIcon(new ImageIcon(ii.getImage().getScaledInstance(newWidth, -1,
                                                                                java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH))); 
      buttonArray[bx][by].setBorderPainted(false);  
      buttonArray[bx][by].setFocusPainted(false);  
      buttonArray[bx][by].setContentAreaFilled(false);
    }

    if(buttonArray[bx][by].getBackground() == Color.DARK_GRAY) {

      ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("star.png");
      int scale = 12;
      int width = ii.getIconWidth();
      int newWidth = width / scale;
      buttonArray[bx][by].setIcon(new ImageIcon(ii.getImage().getScaledInstance(newWidth, -1,
                                                                                java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH))); 
      buttonArray[bx][by].setBorderPainted(false);  
      buttonArray[bx][by].setFocusPainted(false);  
      buttonArray[bx][by].setContentAreaFilled(false);
    }

    if(buttonArray[bx][by].getBackground() == Color.CYAN) {

      ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("pentagon.png");
      int scale = 14;
      int width = ii.getIconWidth();
      int newWidth = width / scale;
      buttonArray[bx][by].setIcon(new ImageIcon(ii.getImage().getScaledInstance(newWidth, -1,
                                                                                java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH))); 
      buttonArray[bx][by].setBorderPainted(false);  
      buttonArray[bx][by].setFocusPainted(false);  
      buttonArray[bx][by].setContentAreaFilled(false);
    }

    if(buttonArray[bx][by].getBackground() == Color.YELLOW) {

      ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("diamond.png");
      int scale = 13;
      int width = ii.getIconWidth();
      int newWidth = width / scale;
      buttonArray[bx][by].setIcon(new ImageIcon(ii.getImage().getScaledInstance(newWidth, -1,
                                                                                java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH))); 
      buttonArray[bx][by].setBorderPainted(false);  
      buttonArray[bx][by].setFocusPainted(false);  
      buttonArray[bx][by].setContentAreaFilled(false);
    }

    if(buttonArray[bx][by].getBackground() == Color.GREEN) {

      ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("hexagon.png");
      int scale = 12;
      int width = ii.getIconWidth();
      int newWidth = width / scale;
      buttonArray[bx][by].setIcon(new ImageIcon(ii.getImage().getScaledInstance(newWidth, -1,
                                                                                java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH))); 
      buttonArray[bx][by].setBorderPainted(false);  
      buttonArray[bx][by].setFocusPainted(false);  
      buttonArray[bx][by].setContentAreaFilled(false);
    }

    if(buttonArray[bx][by].getBackground() == Color.RED) {

      ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("octagon.png");
      int scale = 14;
      int width = ii.getIconWidth();
      int newWidth = width / scale;
      buttonArray[bx][by].setIcon(new ImageIcon(ii.getImage().getScaledInstance(newWidth, -1,
                                                                                java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH))); 
      buttonArray[bx][by].setBorderPainted(false);  
      buttonArray[bx][by].setFocusPainted(false);  
      buttonArray[bx][by].setContentAreaFilled(false);
    }

    if(buttonArray[bx][by].getBackground() == Color.GRAY) {

      ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("marksquare.png");
      int scale = 14;
      int width = ii.getIconWidth();
      int newWidth = width / scale;
      buttonArray[bx][by].setIcon(new ImageIcon(ii.getImage().getScaledInstance(newWidth, -1,
                                                                                java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH))); 
      buttonArray[bx][by].setBorderPainted(false);  
      buttonArray[bx][by].setFocusPainted(false);  
      buttonArray[bx][by].setContentAreaFilled(false);
    }
  }


  public void swapColors(int bx1, int bx2, int by1, int by2) {

    if(marked[bx1][by1] != true && marked[bx2][by2] != true) {

      Color buttonColor1 = buttonArray[bx1][by1].getBackground();
      Color buttonColor2 = buttonArray[bx2][by2].getBackground();
      buttonArray[bx1][by1].setBackground(buttonColor2);
      buttonArray[bx2][by2].setBackground(buttonColor1);
      Icon buttonImage1 = buttonArray[bx1][by1].getIcon();
      Icon buttonImage2 = buttonArray[bx2][by2].getIcon();
      buttonArray[bx1][by1].setIcon(buttonImage2);
      buttonArray[bx2][by2].setIcon(buttonImage1);
      this.checkMatch(bx2, by2);
      turnCount++;
    }
  }

  public void checkMatch(int bx, int by) {

    int grayCount = 0;
    int endX = bx;
    int startX = bx;
    int endY = by;
    int startY = by;

    for(int i = bx; rows - 1 > i && buttonArray[i][by].getBackground() == buttonArray[i+1][by].getBackground(); i++) {
      endX = i + 1;
    }

    for(int i = bx; i > 0 && buttonArray[i][by].getBackground() == buttonArray[i - 1][by].getBackground(); i--) {
      startX = i - 1;
    }

    for(int i = by; columns - 1> i &&  buttonArray[bx][i].getBackground() == buttonArray[bx][i + 1].getBackground(); i++) {
      endY = i + 1;
    }

    for(int i = by;columns > i && i> 0 && buttonArray[bx][i].getBackground() == buttonArray[bx][i - 1].getBackground(); i--) {
      startY = i - 1;
    }

    if(Math.abs(endY - startY) > 1) {
      for(int i = startY; i <= endY; i++) {
        buttonArray[bx][i].setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("marksquare.png");
        int scale = 13;
        int width = ii.getIconWidth();
        int newWidth = width / scale;
        buttonArray[bx][i].setIcon(new ImageIcon(ii.getImage().getScaledInstance(newWidth, -1,
                                                                                 java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH))); 
        buttonArray[bx][i].setBorderPainted(false);  
        buttonArray[bx][i].setFocusPainted(false);  
        buttonArray[bx][i].setContentAreaFilled(false);
        marked[bx][i] = true;
      }
    }

    if(Math.abs(endX - startX) > 1) {
      for(int i = startX; i <= endX; i++) {
        buttonArray[i][by].setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("marksquare.png");
        int scale = 13;
        int width = ii.getIconWidth();
        int newWidth = width / scale;
        buttonArray[i][by].setIcon(new ImageIcon(ii.getImage().getScaledInstance(newWidth, -1,
                                                                                 java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH))); 
        buttonArray[i][by].setBorderPainted(false);  
        buttonArray[i][by].setFocusPainted(false);  
        buttonArray[i][by].setContentAreaFilled(false);
        marked[i][by] = true;
      }
    }
  }

  public void checkForWin() {

    int grayCount = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
      for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {

        if(buttonArray[i][j].getBackground() == Color.GRAY) {
          grayCount++;
        }
      }
    }

    if(grayCount == (rows*columns)) {
      System.out.println("YOU WON in " + turnCount + " legal moves.");
    }
  }

  public static void main (String args[]) {

    JFrame promptFrame = new JFrame();
    JOptionPane prompt = new JOptionPane();
    String row = prompt.showInputDialog(promptFrame, "Please enter the number of rows", "Welcome to Yakobian's Jewels!", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    String column = prompt.showInputDialog(promptFrame, "Please enter the number of columns", "Welcome to Yakobian's Jewels!", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    String numberJewels = prompt.showInputDialog(promptFrame, "Please enter the number of different colors for your Jewels", "Welcome to Yakobian's Jewels!", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

    try {
      Jewelswithec j = new Jewelswithec(Integer.parseInt(row), Integer.parseInt(column), Integer.parseInt(numberJewels));
    }

    catch(NumberFormatException e) {
      Jewelswithec j = new Jewelswithec();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: please make the code smaller and relevant. For example you don't need to put all the `if-else` of `(buttonArray[bx][by].getBackground() == color)` at all. Just put  two of them, and shrink your code likewise

Comment: don't to use Mouse or KeyListener for JButton, both event are implemented in JButton API and properly

Comment: Alternatively, consider the approach shown in this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2562685/230513) and [variation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2563350/230513).