# Building a chess board in Java

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent, rectangles

I am trying to create a chess board using the fillrect function in java.The code doesn't seem to be working and adds only the first statement in the frame.Even if I remove the for loop (that prints 64 squares ) and make only 2 add statements,it still prints only the first of them.Here is the code:

```
import javax.swing.* ;
import java.awt.* ;
public class ChessBoard extends JFrame {
    private int i;
    public ChessBoard (){
    setLayout(new GridLayout(8,8,0,0));
    // there are 64 squares 
    for(i=0; i<64 ;i++){

        if ((i % 2) == 0) //switches between black and white squares
            add(new DrawRect("WHITE"));
        else
            add(new DrawRect("BLACK"));

    }
}
}
class DrawRect extends JPanel{
    private String ngjyra = "BLACK";
    public DrawRect(String b) {
    ngjyra = b ;

    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent (Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (ngjyra.equals("BLACK"))
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        else 
                g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight()); 
           //add the square with the specified color

}
}
```

Comment: "adds only the first statement in the frame" what does it mean? Why can't you just call setBackground() for the cells' JPanels?

Comment: if I remove the loop,and make 2 add statements (consistion of a black and white Rect) it adds only the first statement to the frame.I am reading a book to learn java and its an exercise that asks for filledrect.And I would like to solve this particular problem.

Comment: Not related to your issue, but why can't `DrawRect` hold the `Color` directly? And if you absolutely need it this way, why a string, and not an enum or int?

Comment: A good idea.Thanks for your info on that one.An int would have been much simpler.

Comment: @Lind an `enum` would be much simpler.

Comment: Color would be simplest.

Comment: See also this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2562685/230513) and [variation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2563350/230513).

Comment: Thanks man,at the end of the semester I have to implement a chess game.I need to learn more,but those examples will help me .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your graphics uses relative coordinates with zero at the top left corner of the component, so the right way to draw rectangle is

```
g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
```

Another issue that your colour assignment code is such that all black and all while cells make vertical stripes. Use instead the logic like

```
    for (int row = 0; row < 8; row++)
        for (int col = 0; col < 8; col++) {
            boolean white = (col % 2 == 0) == (row % 2 == 0);
            add(new DrawRect(white ? "WHITE" : "BLACK"));
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your info.I had a logic error in the loop which assigned colors,and I didn't use fillrect correctly.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is with `getX()` and `getY()`, they return the same value for each of your `DrawRect` so they will be drawn one above the other. You could use `setBackground` instead:

```
class DrawRect extends JPanel {
   private Color ngjyra = Color.BLACK;

   public DrawRect(Color color) {
      ngjyra = color ;
      setBackground(ngjyra);
}
```

However you still have a mistake in your loop logic, as you will see if you try the code i posted above.

Comment: I don't think your idea is correct.When I add two statemens like add(new DrawRect("WHITE")); add(new DrawRect("BLACK")); it does not add a black square,but add's a white one.This removes the idea that they are drawn one above the other.The setBackground would be used if I used JPanels ... I am drawing rect.

Comment: Your DrawRect class is extending a JPanel. You could use setBackground on it to get the same effect without needing to worry about the paint method.

Comment: As I said I want to draw rect.This is what the exercise asks.I must use the paint method.

Comment: Your assumption is wrong. In fact, both `DrawRect`s are added, but drawn on top of each other. It just *looks* like only one is drawn.

Comment: Your class is a JPanel, so you can just use `setBackground`.

Comment: Edgar Boda your idea was right.I got it now.Thanks for your answer also.It seems I can not give 2 right answers ... :P

Comment: haha don't worry, after all Audrius' answer is more what you wanted anyway ;-)