# Using mouseListeners and mouseMotionListeners in internal frame (Java)

Tags: java, swing

I have created a desktop pane and internal frame for chess application. The outer window have Menu such as new game. It works pretty great. But the problem which I am facing is with mouse events in the internal frame. As my Internal frame is my chessboard with chess pieces. The mouse events were working when I was not using desktop pane with an internal frame just a simple frame approach for the game. When I switched my code to use desktop pane with internal frame my mouse events stops working.

I hope my problem is clear to everyone and hoping for a useful answer. 
here's the source code:

`frame` is the internal frame in which the chess game lies. The desktop pane should be above the frame and have menu bar for new game and quit.

```
 public void createFrame() {

    JInternalFrame frame = new JInternalFrame();
```

This is my chess board

```
JLayeredPane layeredPane;
JPanel chessBoard;
JLabel chessPiece;
int xAdjustment;
int yAdjustment;

Dimension boardSize = new Dimension(400, 400);
//FlowLayout flow=new FlowLayout();
layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
getContentPane().add(layeredPane);
layeredPane.setPreferredSize(boardSize);
layeredPane.addMouseListener(this);
layeredPane.addMouseMotionListener(this);
chessBoard = new JPanel();
layeredPane.add(chessBoard, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
chessBoard.setLayout(new GridLayout(8, 8));
chessBoard.setPreferredSize(boardSize);
chessBoard.setBounds(0, 0, boardSize.width, boardSize.height);
for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
    JPanel square = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    chessBoard.add(square);
    int row = (i / 8) % 2;
    if (row == 0) {
        square.setBackground(i % 2 == 0 ? Color.LIGHT_GRAY : Color.RED);
    } else {
        square.setBackground(i % 2 == 0 ? Color.RED : Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    }
}
```

Chessboard ended. These are my chess pices which contains images of pieces which are placed on the board to be moved

```
JLabel piece;

    piece = new JLabel( new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Moemmer\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects

\\ChessGame\\src\\Images\\23797642-complete-wooden-chess-set-with-s-full-complement-

of-chess-pieces-in-both-colours-lined-up-in-rows-is - Copy.jpg") );



JPanel panel = (JPanel)chessBoard.getComponent(0);



panel.add(piece);


piece = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Moemmer\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects

\\ChessGame\\src\\Images\\23797642-complete-wooden-chess-set-with-s-full-complement-

of-chess-pieces-in-both-colours-lined-up-in-rows-is - Copy.jpg"));

panel = (JPanel)chessBoard.getComponent(15);



panel.add(piece);

piece = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Moemmer\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects

\\ChessGame\\src\\Images\\23797642-complete-wooden-chess-set-with-s-full-complement-

of-chess-pieces-in-both-colours-lined-up-in-rows-is - Copy.jpg"));

panel = (JPanel)chessBoard.getComponent(16);



panel.add(piece);



piece = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Moemmer\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects

\\ChessGame\\src\\Images\\23797642-complete-wooden-chess-set-with-s-full-complement-

of-chess-pieces-in-both-colours-lined-up-in-rows-is - Copy.jpg"));



panel = (JPanel)chessBoard.getComponent(20);

panel.add(piece);          chess pieces code ended)


        frame.setVisible(true); 



        desktop.add(frame);


        frame.setBounds(20,20,410,450);



        frame.add(layeredPane);




        try {



            frame.setSelected(true);




        } catch (java.beans.PropertyVetoException e) {}




    }

    //Quit the application.


    public void quit() {



        System.exit(0);
    }
    @Override
```

These are the mouse events which worked well when the code was not converted to internal frame and used desktop pane...

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){



chessPiece = null;



Component c = chessBoard.findComponentAt(e.getX(), e.getY());



if (c instanceof JPanel)



return;


Point parentLocation = c.getParent().getLocation();



xAdjustment = parentLocation.x - e.getX();



yAdjustment = parentLocation.y - e.getY();



chessPiece = (JLabel)c;


chessPiece.setLocation(e.getX() + xAdjustment, e.getY() + yAdjustment);



chessPiece.setSize(chessPiece.getWidth(), chessPiece.getHeight());



layeredPane.add(chessPiece, JLayeredPane.DRAG_LAYER);


}
    @Override


 public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {



if (chessPiece == null) return;


chessPiece.setLocation(me.getX() + xAdjustment, me.getY() + yAdjustment);


}
//Drop the chess piece back onto the chess board
    @Override


    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {


if(chessPiece == null) return;


chessPiece.setVisible(false);


Component c = chessBoard.findComponentAt(e.getX(), e.getY());


if (c instanceof JLabel){


Container parent = c.getParent();




parent.remove(0);



parent.add( chessPiece );




}



else {



Container parent = (Container)c;



parent.add( chessPiece );



}



chessPiece.setVisible(true);



}



    @Override




    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
}
    @Override


    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {


}
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){
}
    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
}
public void BackgroundImageJFrame()
{

}



Displaying the frame


private static void createAndShowGUI() {


        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);




        Game frame = new Game();


        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);






        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
```

Main Method>>

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {




        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();

            }
        });


    }
```

Comment: no one wants to look at unformatted code

Comment: See also this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2562685/230513) and [variation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2563350/230513), as well as this [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21142686/230513).

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 2) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow. 3) A single blank line of white space in source code is *always* enough.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant. 4) See also [Making a robust, resizable Chess GUI](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21142686/418556).