# How to work with MouseListener. Don't work GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, chess

I am trying to write simple chess application based on this tutorial: https://proghammer.wordpress.com/2010/08/10/chess01-dragging-game-pieces/
I use this code with some changes, and it doesn't work. I am really new in Java GUI programming, can someone tell me what I do wrong.

UPDATE:
I am trying to correct my mistakes, when I asked this question, I tryed to debug this. And I think that problem is in `ChessGame` class. Methods like `mouseDragged()` are working but nothing changed. Pieces did't drag. And I asking for helping with this.
There is too much code, but this code only for providing full information. I repeat, I think that problem is in `ChessGame` or (maybe in `ChessView`), other code is only for understanding structure.

This is my code:

```
public class ChessView extends JPanel {

ChessBoard board;

private static final int BOARD_START_X = 220;
private static final int BOARD_START_Y = 120;

private static final int TILE_WIDTH = 45;
private static final int TILE_HEIGHT = 45;

private Image background;

public ChessView() {
    board = new ChessBoard();
    // load and set background image
    URL backgroundImg = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("background.jpg");
    this.background = new ImageIcon(backgroundImg).getImage();


    // add mouse listeners to enable drag and drop
    ChessGame game = new ChessGame(board, this);
    this.addMouseListener(game);
    this.addMouseMotionListener(game);

    // create application frame and set visible
    //
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.add(this);
    f.setResizable(false);
    f.setSize(this.background.getWidth(null), this.background.getHeight(null));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new ChessView();
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(this.background, 0, 0, null);
    int row;
    for(int i = 0; i < board.getHeight(); i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < board.getWidth(); j++) {
            Piece piece = board.getBoardAsArray()[i][j];
            if (piece.getClass() != EmptySquare.class) {
                if (piece.getColor() == other.Color.WHITE) {
                    if (piece.getClass() != Pawn.class) row = 7;
                    else row = 6;
                } else {
                    if (piece.getClass() != Pawn.class) row = 0;
                    else row = 1;
                }
                int x = BOARD_START_X + (TILE_WIDTH * j);
                int y = BOARD_START_Y + (TILE_HEIGHT * row);
                piece.setX(x);
                piece.setY(y);
                g.drawImage(piece.getImage(), x, y, null);

            }
        }
    }
}

public ChessBoard getBoard() {
    return board;
}
}
```

This is my Listener:

```
public class ChessGame implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {

private ChessBoard board;
private ChessView view;

private Piece dragPiece;
private int dragOffsetX;
private int dragOffsetY;


public ChessGame(ChessBoard board, ChessView chessGui) {
    this.board = board;
    this.view = chessGui;
}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    int x = e.getPoint().x;
    int y = e.getPoint().y;

    for(int i = 0; i < view.getBoard().getHeight(); i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < view.getBoard().getWidth(); j++) {
            Piece piece = view.getBoard().getBoardAsArray()[i][j];
            if (piece.getClass() != EmptySquare.class) {
                if (mouseOverPiece(piece, x, y)) {
                    this.dragOffsetX = x - piece.getX();
                    this.dragOffsetY = y - piece.getY();
                    this.dragPiece = piece;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * check whether the mouse is currently over this piece
 * @param piece the playing piece
 * @param x x coordinate of mouse
 * @param y y coordinate of mouse
 * @return true if mouse is over the piece
 */
private boolean mouseOverPiece(Piece piece, int x, int y) {
    return piece.getX() <= x
            && piece.getX()+piece.getWidth() >= x
            && piece.getY() <= y
            && piece.getY()+piece.getHeight() >= y;
}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
    this.dragPiece = null;
}

@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent evt) {
    if(this.dragPiece != null){
        this.dragPiece.setX(evt.getPoint().x - this.dragOffsetX);
        this.dragPiece.setY(evt.getPoint().y - this.dragOffsetY);
        this.view.repaint();
    }

}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {}

@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent arg0) {}

}
```

This is my board representation:

```
public class ChessBoard {
private Piece[][] board = new Piece[8][8];

private final int WIDTH = 8;
private final int HEIGHT = 8;

//Write a NullPiece class or contain nulls is 2-5 rows?
public ChessBoard () {
    setStartBoard(); //rewrite
}

public int getHeight() {
    return HEIGHT;
}

public int getWidth() {
    return WIDTH;
}

public Piece[][] getBoardAsArray() {
    return board;
}

public ArrayList<Piece> getBoardAsArrayList() {
    ArrayList<Piece> list = new ArrayList<Piece>();
     for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < HEIGHT; j++) {
             list.add(board[i][j]);
         }
     }
    return list;
}

Piece firstWhiteRook = new Rook(Color.WHITE);
Piece secondWhiteRook = new Rook(Color.WHITE);
Piece firstWhiteKnight = new Knight(Color.WHITE);
Piece secondWhiteKnight = new Knight(Color.WHITE);
Piece firstWhiteBishop = new Bishop(Color.WHITE);
Piece secondWhiteBishop = new Bishop(Color.WHITE);
Piece whiteQueen = new Queen(Color.WHITE);
Piece whiteKing = new King(Color.WHITE);
Piece firstWhitePawn = new Pawn(Color.WHITE);
Piece secondWhitePawn = new Pawn(Color.WHITE);
Piece thirdWhitePawn = new Pawn(Color.WHITE);
Piece fourthWhitePawn = new Pawn(Color.WHITE);
Piece fifthWhitePawn = new Pawn(Color.WHITE);
Piece sixthWhitePawn = new Pawn(Color.WHITE);
Piece seventhWhitePawn = new Pawn(Color.WHITE);
Piece eighthWhitePawn = new Pawn(Color.WHITE);

Piece firstBlackRook = new Rook(Color.BLACK);
Piece secondBlackRook = new Rook(Color.BLACK);
Piece firstBlackKnight = new Knight(Color.BLACK);
Piece secondBlackKnight = new Knight(Color.BLACK);
Piece firstBlackBishop = new Bishop(Color.BLACK);
Piece secondBlackBishop = new Bishop(Color.BLACK);
Piece blackQueen = new Queen(Color.BLACK);
Piece blackKing = new King(Color.BLACK);
Piece firstBlackPawn = new Pawn(Color.BLACK);
Piece secondBlackPawn = new Pawn(Color.BLACK);
Piece thirdBlackPawn = new Pawn(Color.BLACK);
Piece fourthBlackPawn = new Pawn(Color.BLACK);
Piece fifthBlackPawn = new Pawn(Color.BLACK);
Piece sixthBlackPawn = new Pawn(Color.BLACK);
Piece seventhBlackPawn = new Pawn(Color.BLACK);
Piece eighthBlackPawn = new Pawn(Color.BLACK);


//TODO: make this more beautiful?
public void setStartBoard() {

    //set color for each piece

    //add all pieces to board
    board[0][0] = firstBlackRook;
    board[0][1] = firstBlackKnight;
    board[0][2] = firstBlackBishop;
    board[0][3] = blackQueen;
    board[0][4] = blackKing;
    board[0][5] = secondBlackBishop;
    board[0][6] = secondBlackKnight;
    board[0][7] = secondBlackRook;

    board[1][0] = firstBlackPawn;
    board[1][1] = secondBlackPawn;
    board[1][2] = thirdBlackPawn;
    board[1][3] = fourthBlackPawn;
    board[1][4] = fifthBlackPawn;
    board[1][5] = sixthBlackPawn;
    board[1][6] = seventhBlackPawn;
    board[1][7] = eighthBlackPawn;


    board[7][0] = firstWhiteRook;
    board[7][1] = firstWhiteKnight;
    board[7][2] = firstWhiteBishop;
    board[7][3] = whiteQueen;
    board[7][4] = whiteKing;
    board[7][5] = secondWhiteBishop;
    board[7][6] = secondWhiteKnight;
    board[7][7] = secondWhiteRook;

    board[6][0] =  firstWhitePawn;
    board[6][1] =  secondWhitePawn;
    board[6][2] =  thirdWhitePawn;
    board[6][3] =  fourthWhitePawn;
    board[6][4] =  fifthWhitePawn;
    board[6][5] =  sixthWhitePawn;
    board[6][6] =  seventhWhitePawn;
    board[6][7] = eighthWhitePawn;

    for(int i = 2; i < 6; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            board[i][j] = new EmptySquare(Color.EMPTY);
        }
    }


}

}
```

This is my Piece implementation:

```
public class PieceImpl implements Piece {

private int x;

private int y;

private static final String NAME = ""; // Only for getName(). Don't use.

private Color color;

private Image image;

public PieceImpl(Color color) {
    this.color = color;
}

public void setColor(Color color) {
    this.color = color;
}

public Color getColor() {
    return color;
}

public Image getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(Image image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public String toString() {
    if (this.getColor() == Color.BLACK) {
        return "b" + NAME;
    } else {
        return "w" + NAME;
    }
}

public int getX() {
    return x;
}

public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
}

public int getY() {
    return y;
}

public void setY(int y) {
    this.y = y;
}

public int getWidth() {
    return image.getWidth(null);
}

public int getHeight() {
    return image.getHeight(null);
}
}
```

This is example of king implementation:

```
public class King extends PieceImpl implements Piece{
private static final String NAME = "K";

public King(Color color) {
    super(color);
    if (this.getColor() == Color.WHITE) {
        URL urlToImage = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("wk.png");
        setImage(new ImageIcon(urlToImage).getImage());
    } else if (this.getColor() == Color.BLACK) {
        URL urlToImage = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("bk.png");
        setImage(new ImageIcon(urlToImage).getImage());
    }
}

public String toString() {
    if (this.getColor() == Color.BLACK) {
        return "b" + NAME;
    } else {
        return "w" + NAME;
    }
}
```

I represent color by enum class:

```
public enum Color {

BLACK("black", 0),
WHITE("white", 1),
EMPTY("empty", -1);

private final String name;
private final int id;

private Color(String name, int id) {
    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

public int getID() {
    return this.id;
}

}
```

This is not only me code, as I say I am trying to study with tutorial. But I want to use my board representation. When I am running application, it's run, and I see the GUI, but mouse events don't work. Can someone tell me where I make a mistake, why mouse events don't work?

Comment: See also this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2562685/230513) and [variation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2563350/230513), as well as this [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21142686/230513).

Comment: did you do any kind of debugging?

Comment: I see this when I searching for some help information, but I am beginner in swing and I don't understand this examples completely, I am only ask why this code don't work?

Comment: *"I am only ask why this code don't work?"*  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).  An MCVE should be a single source code file (but it can contain more than one class).  Like the code in most of the examples linked by @trashgod.

Comment: What is this line: `if (piece.getColor() == other.Color.WHITE) {` ? specifically what is `other`?

Comment: Ok but there are few unanswered questions: 1st is: In your code of event listeners your have set the `this.dragPiece.setX(evt.getPoint().x - this.dragOffsetX); this.dragPiece.setY(evt.getPoint().y - this.dragOffsetY);` but does it change the location of your piece in the `board` class

Comment: @AndrewThompson
OK, I post so mush code, because I don't understand where I am wrong, and I trying to give full information about my problem. I understand that this is to much code, and this code not good understandable, I am sorry for this.

Comment: @ReutSharabani it's package contains Color

Comment: @AlexeySharov first step is to add some logs or debug your code to zoom in on the problem, otherwise it's hard to help since this is a lot of code and we can't even reproduce the problem locally.

Comment: *"I post so mush code, because I don't understand where I am wrong"* Remove part of the code.  Does the problem still happen?  If so, leave that out entirely and remove more code.  This is all explained in the SSCCE document.  Go back and read it again, carefully.  If you could not be bothered creating an MCVE/SSCCE, most people couldn't be bothered helping.   Also, it is (lack of MCVE) part of a **close reason.**

Comment: @Blip I know that I don' change anything in `board`, and this is my future task I think, but know I am want to dragging pieces. Maybe logic of my program is wrong too, as I say I only studying GUI application.

Comment: @AndrewThompson
This is minimum of code, what must be working, if I delete anything, application will not run.
I am trying to debug this, and I know this method of searching bug, but in my situation, i think, it couldn't help.

Comment: first I would suggest that you add a `System.out.println("Mouse Dragging!");` just before your line `this.view.repaint();` in your `mouseDragged` method and check if the output is there in the console or not.

Comment: @Blip 
I do this before you tell it. My mistake is that I don't write about some debug what I make. 
This is working, program don't `repaint` anything, but this events are existing.

Comment: So, I think that all parts of program excluding `ChessGame` is working wright.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel from your comments and debugging information that you have shared is that your `mouseListener` is working perfectly. So the problem lies somewhere else. Studying your code I find that in your `ChessView` class' `paintComponent` method resigns the `piece` variable's  `x` and `y` in the code :

```
int x = BOARD_START_X + (TILE_WIDTH * j);
int y = BOARD_START_Y + (TILE_HEIGHT * row);
piece.setX(x);
piece.setY(y);
```

And draws it on the the board in position `x` and `y`. So this is basically undoing what you have done in your `mouseListener` :

```
this.dragPiece.setX(evt.getPoint().x - this.dragOffsetX);
this.dragPiece.setY(evt.getPoint().y - this.dragOffsetY);
```

So you should have a way of setting the the `piece` in the `board` class' new location

OR

you should have a system to store the initial values of `x` and `y` for each piece and should not reset the `x` and `y` values in the `paintComponent` and should call

```
g.drawImage(piece.getImage(), piece.getX(), piece.getY(), null);
```