# How to create an exact JPanel mirror on top of another JPanel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, gridbaglayout

I'm trying to create a checkers game using Swing and I have the board set up already [(here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDEV6.png).

Each individual tile is placed onto the GUI in a JPanel that is organized via a GridBagLayout manager. In order to put the individual checker pieces onto the tiles, I want to create another JPanel that is an exact copy of the JPanel that holds the board tiles. The copy-JPanel will hold the checker pieces and be transparent, allowing the checker pieces to sit on top of the gameboard.

How will I be able to create this second JPanel? And if it is not possible, what is a better alternative to create the checker pieces on the checkerboard.

Comment: `I want to create another JPanel that is an exact copy of the JPanel that holds the board tiles.` - not sure why you want to do this. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561690/placing-component-on-glass-pane/2562685#2562685 for a different approach.

Comment: *"what is a better alternative"* A `GridLayout` of `JBuitton` components. Here is [an example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21142686/418556) based around a chess board.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your design could be improved and simplified. Far simpler is to simply create a grid of JPanel cells, held in a GridLayout, and then add JLabel pieces to any individual cell that nees to hold a piece. No need to mirror or duplicate anything. Then if you want to give the user the ability to click and drag pieces, in your mouse listeners code, lift the piece into the glasspane, or use your own JLayeredPane, and move it.

For example, try running this program to see exactly what I mean. It only has one piece, and the logic is simple -- only allow dropping of piece onto a dark square, but it does demonstrate the concepts:

[image]

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ChessEg extends JPanel {
    private static final int IMG_W = 60;
    private static final int CELL_WIDTH = 80;
    private static final Color PIECE_COLOR = Color.RED.darker();
    private ChessBoardPanel chessBoardPanel = new ChessBoardPanel(CELL_WIDTH);
    private JLabel pieceLabel = new JLabel();

    public ChessEg() {
        ChessBrdPanelListener pieceListener = new ChessBrdPanelListener();
        chessBoardPanel.addMouseListener(pieceListener);
        chessBoardPanel.addMouseMotionListener(pieceListener);
        pieceLabel.setIcon(createPieceIcon());
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(chessBoardPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        chessBoardPanel.getCellAt(1, 0).add(pieceLabel);
    }

    private Icon createPieceIcon() {
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(IMG_W, IMG_W, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g2 = img.createGraphics();
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.setColor(PIECE_COLOR);
        g2.fillOval(2, 2, IMG_W - 4, IMG_W - 4);
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2f));
        g2.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        g2.drawOval(2, 2, IMG_W - 4, IMG_W - 4);
        g2.dispose();
        return new ImageIcon(img);
    }

    public boolean isNewChessCellValid(ChessCell newChessCell) {
        // right now, just checks if placing on a dark square
        // TODO: improve logic
        return ChessBoardPanel.DARK_COLOR.equals(newChessCell.getBackground());
    }

    private class ChessBrdPanelListener extends MouseAdapter {
        private JLabel label;
        private ChessCell originalChessCell;
        private JPanel glassPane;
        private Point gpP;
        private ChessCell newChessCell;

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            if (e.getButton() != MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
                return;
            }
            JPanel src = (JPanel) e.getSource();
            Component comp = src.getComponentAt(e.getPoint());
            if (comp != null && ((JComponent) comp).getComponentCount() == 1) {
                originalChessCell = (ChessCell) comp;
                label = (JLabel) originalChessCell.getComponent(0);
            } else {
                return;
            }
            originalChessCell.remove(label);
            originalChessCell.revalidate();
            originalChessCell.repaint();
            glassPane = (JPanel) SwingUtilities.getRootPane(originalChessCell).getGlassPane();
            glassPane.setVisible(true);
            gpP = glassPane.getLocationOnScreen();
            glassPane.setLayout(null);
            int x = e.getXOnScreen() - gpP.x - label.getWidth() / 2;
            int y = e.getYOnScreen() - gpP.y - label.getHeight() / 2;
            label.setLocation(x, y);
            label.setSize(label.getPreferredSize());
            glassPane.add(label);
            glassPane.repaint();
            e.consume();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            if (label == null) {
                return;
            }
            int x = e.getXOnScreen() - gpP.x - label.getWidth() / 2;
            int y = e.getYOnScreen() - gpP.y - label.getHeight() / 2;
            label.setLocation(x, y);
            repaint();
            JPanel src = (JPanel) e.getSource();
            Component comp = src.getComponentAt(e.getPoint());
            if (comp != null) {
                newChessCell = (ChessCell) comp;
                if (isNewChessCellValid(newChessCell)) {
                    newChessCell.add(label);
                } else {
                    originalChessCell.add(label);
                }
            } else {
                originalChessCell.add(label);
            }


            label = null;
            glassPane.setVisible(false);
            revalidate();
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            if (label == null) {
                return;
            }
            int x = e.getXOnScreen() - gpP.x - label.getWidth() / 2;
            int y = e.getYOnScreen() - gpP.y - label.getHeight() / 2;
            label.setLocation(x, y);
            repaint();
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        ChessEg mainPanel = new ChessEg();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Chess Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class ChessBoardPanel extends JPanel {
    public static final Color DARK_COLOR = new Color(180, 85, 0);
    public static final Color LIGHT_COLOR = new Color(220, 190, 160);
    private int cellWidth;
    private ChessCell[][] panelGrid = new ChessCell[8][8];

    public ChessBoardPanel(int cellWidth) {
        this.cellWidth = cellWidth;
        setLayout(new GridLayout(8, 8));
        for (int i = 0; i < panelGrid.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < panelGrid[i].length; j++) {
                char rank = (char) ('8' - i);
                char file = (char) ('a' + j);
                panelGrid[i][j] = new ChessCell(rank, file);
                panelGrid[i][j].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(cellWidth, cellWidth));
                Color bg = i % 2 == j % 2 ? LIGHT_COLOR : DARK_COLOR;
                panelGrid[i][j].setBackground(bg);
                add(panelGrid[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }

    public JPanel getCellAt(int i, int j) {
        return panelGrid[i][j];
    }

    public int getCellWidth() {
        return cellWidth;
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class ChessCell extends JPanel {
    private char rank;
    private char file;

    public ChessCell(char rank, char file) {
        super(new GridBagLayout());
        this.rank = rank;
        this.file = file;
    }

    public char getRank() {
        return rank;
    }

    public char getFile() {
        return file;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ChessCell [rank=" + rank + ", file=" + file + "]";
    }
}
```

Comment: The individual game tiles are created via a JLabel ImageIcon. How would I overlap the game piece JLabel onto the tile JLabel?

Comment: @GandalfDaGrey: make the tile a JPanel, not a JLabel, and display its image in its paintComponent method. Or else give your JLabel a decent layout manager, such as a GridBagLayout. With this layout, any single component added to the JLabel is automatically centered. Otherwise you're talking about using a JLayeredPane with kludgy math.

Comment: @GandalfDaGrey: see example above for what I mean.

Comment: Thank you! Setting the JLabels to use the GridBagLayout manager and then simply adding the checker pieces Label to the tile label worked perfectly.